# Visual Studio Code - how to view previous searches?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I came from **Sublime** to **Visual Studio Code** and I'm looking for the history of searches in the Visual Code , what was in the Sublime with  -

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

and then just press <kbd>↕</kbd> to navigate between previous/next search.

How could I get the same functionality on Visual Studio Code on its search text field ?

[image]

My current Version is 1.5.2

Comment: I looked it up and verified that it now works. It works as long as your instance is open. As soon as you quit the app and come back, it's all gone.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

> <kbd>Up</kbd>: Shows the previous term in history
>
> <kbd>Down</kbd>: Shows the next term in history

You can customize the keybinding to your liking using `history.showPrevious` and `history.showNext`

Comment: Thanks. Man that action needs to be more discoverable.

Comment: In a Mac it´s option+up / down. And yes, not only should be more discoverable, but also showing a short list preview of the history will be welcome (just like Atom does).

Comment: It only works until you close Visual Studio Code on the latest version 1.23.1, after that search history is cleared.

Comment: Is there a way to preserve search history?

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve that part of history that matches what you typed? Because after a while it becomes useless to use the arrows to search for something that you typed a month ago, and it looks like searches performed with the arrows are not added to the history :(

Comment: Thanks nbloqs this appears completely undiscoverable on the Mac

Answer (score 46):

It's <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> in the search edit box.
It used to be that you had to use <kbd>alt</kbd>, but later they added just the arrow keys by themselves. The keyboard shortcut is customizable under history.showPrevious and history.showNext

Comment: Hmm. There should definitely be an ui for it. It's hard to find the search query you want when you have similar & long queries.

Answer (score 3):

definitely it should be accessible by UI. Although the minimalistic UI is the best of VSC

you can navigate search recent history by Alt+up/donw

Comment: Please provide quality answers until you can write comments. Your answer here is a comment and not a real answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no search history in Visual Studio Code. But it's part of the September milestones as you can see here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5508
So the feature will probably be shipped in October 2016.

Comment: This answer is outdated.