# Visual studio code: search history?

Tags: visual-studio

Performing search A
Performing search B
...

I would like to have a look at the latest search texts I made.

Is there a way to access the search history in Visual Studio Code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **alt+up arrow** and **alt+down arrow** to browse through your search history (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42856012/1773450)

Comment: If you see a duplicate question (one that is answered somewhere else), please flag it as such (use the "flag" link under the question's tags). I've already handled this one.

Comment: I was looking for this actually, thanks